# Regular Expression in Python strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to validate a string that satisfies the below three conditions using regular expression

1. The special characters allowed are (. , _ , - ).
2. Should contain only lower-case characters.
3. Should not start or end with special character.

To satisfy the above conditions, I have created a format as below

```
^[^\W_][a-z\.,_-]+
```

This pattern works fine up to second character. However, this pattern is failing for the 3rd and subsequent characters if those contains any special character or upper cases characters.

Example:

Pattern Works for the string S@yanthan but not for Sa@yanthan. I am expecting that pattern to pass even if the third and subsequent characters contains any special characters or upper case characters. Can you suggest me where this pattern goes wrong please? Below is the snippet of the code.

```
import re 

a = "Sayanthan"
exp = re.search("^[^\W_][a-z\.,_-]+",a)

if exp:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Just to clarify. the allowed special characters are comma seperated? So you allow a dot, an underscore and hyphen?

Comment: `Sayanthan` should not match when `Should contain only lower-case characters`. The `@` is not listed as a special character.

Comment: The allowed special characters are dot, comma, an underscore and hyphen. Also the third condition is "should not start with Special character" instead of "should not start or end with Special character"

Comment: Please note that your specifications do ***not*** line up with the actual sample you give!

Answer (score 1):

Based on you initial rules I'd go with:

```
^[a-z](?:[.,_-]*[a-z])*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/09VL2z/12).

However, you mentioned in the comments:

> *"Also the third condition is "should not start with Special character" instead of "should not start or end with Special character""*

In that case you could use:

```
^[a-z][-.,_a-z]*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/09VL2z/11)

Comment: How does $ turned out to be a significant factor in validating the given expression? Can you explain please? *  quantifier would look for the 0 or more occurrences of the preceding character or groups. So I thought just stopping the pattern * would be suffice to validate the expression with the given conditions. So, can you explain me the role of $ in this expression please?

Comment: Since we want to match up to the end of the string this *End String Ancor* is important to get the character class before it match up to the actual end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried `^[^\W_][a-z.,_-]+` starts with `[^\W_]` which will match any word char except an underscore, so it could also be an uppercase char.

Then `[a-z.,_-]+` will match 1+ times any of the listed, which means the string can also end with a comma for example.

Looking at the conditions listed, you could use:

```
^[a-z](?:[a-z.,_-]*[a-z])?\Z
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]` Match a lower case char a-z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-z.,_-]*[a-z]` Match 0+ occurrences of the listed ending with a-z
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `\Z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKwhIS/1)

Comment: Close to what I had initially (updated my answer) however looking at the comments by OP underneath the question it seems rules have somewhat changed. Just wanted to give you a headsup.